# How are Assassin's Creed 1 and 2 related to Assassin's Creed 4?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

I played 1st and 2nd series and both parts of 2nd (Brotherhood and Revelations) but didn't played 3rd and now playing 4rth (The Black Flag). But I can't relate them to previous just like 1st and 2nd are connected.

Is there any connection between games?

Answer (score 6):

**The first six games in the series<sup>(1)</sup> follow the genetic heritage of Desmond Miles**, who is the protagonist in the overarching framing story which is set in 2012, which is narrated throughout these games through vignettes set in present times.

**In each game, the player takes up the role of another ancestor** (Altaïr Ibn-La'Ahad in *Assassin's Creed*, Ezio Auditore in *Assassin's Creed II*, *Brotherhood*, and *Revelations*, and Edward Kenway in *Assassin's Creed IV: Black Flag*).

A quick sketch of the series' premise (containing very mild spoilers):

> Desmond Miles is the youngest descendant in a lineage of assassins. He is abducted by Abstergo Industries, a pharmaceutical company that forces him to take part in a highly secretive project. He is put into the Animus, a neurologically controlled virtual reality machine that makes Desmond relive the lives of his ancestors. By 'browsing' chronologically through these genetic memories, Abstergo hopes to find the Pieces of Eden, ancient relics said to harbor divine power.

For more information, check [the Wikipedia page on the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed), read up on the overarching story on [Den of Geek](https://www.denofgeek.com/us/games/assassins-creed/235887/assassins-creed-origins-and-the-story-so-far), or watch it as it is explained to you by [Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/videos/2018/10/10/17960700/assassins-creed-odyssey-recap-summary-video), or, more extensively, by [LazerzZ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85A0aE-SXYo).

<sup>(1): Assassin's Creed, Assassin's Creed II, Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood, Assassin's Creed: Revelations, Assassin's Creed III, Assassin's Creed IV: Black Flag</sup>

Comment: You missed the player character(s) from Assassins Creeed 3, Edward Kenways son and his son, no personality native american (seriously, I never learned his name, because he was such a dull character). Otherwise, good answer, +1

Comment: Thank you. I did not mention ACIII, because the OP only asked after the ones I mentioned. And you mean Connor (or Ratonhnhaké:ton, which I had to look up again :)).